# Places SDK for Android

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-developers-console, google-places-autocomplete

I have Google's Place Autocomplete in my app **but occasionally when I touch the search button it comes, then disappears**.

Ive added my debug and release SHA-1's to the project and API Keys on the Google Developer's Console.

It doesnt occur all the time. On some days it happens all days. The error on the console is 403 - {"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"Requests from this Android client application com.ganger.package are blocked."}],"code":403}

Ive also increased my quota to 150,000 requests per day.

Meta data is also included in the application tag of the manifest.

```
    try {
        AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
                .setCountry("GH")
                .build();
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                        .setFilter(autocompleteFilter)
                        .build(AddressActivity.this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }
```

This is the link to the graph on the Google Console.- https://ibb.co/cp4hFp.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I came across the same problem and figured out, that it occured because I forgot to add the SHA-1 fingerprint of the debug keystore from a secondary computer that I use for developing. Also I guess that the fingerprint can change, when you reinstall Android Studio or SDK tools.